# Concise way to print vectors/matrices of unequal length to .txt file - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, printf

I have three matrices `A B C` containing numerical data and which are of unequal lengths (e.g. `A=88x1`, `B=121x1`, `C=240x1` - lengths are variable between data sets). In order to print these to a .txt file without `padarray` and to fill in the unequal lengths with white space instead, i've been using:

```
con = [{A} {B} {C}];
lens = cellfun('length',con);
max_length = max(lens);
con_reg = cell(max_length,numel(lens));
con_reg(:) = {''};
con_reg(bsxfun(@le,[1:max_length]',lens)) = cellstr(num2str(vertcat(con{:})));
wspace = repmat({char(9)},max_length,1);
out_str = [];
for iter = 1:numel(con)
    out_str = [out_str char(con_reg(:,iter)) char(wspace)];
end
out_cell = cellstr(out_str);
ext = '.txt';
filename = strcat((genotype{1}),'-',num2str(threshold),'bpThresh',ext);
fid1 = fopen(filename{1},'wt');
for row = 1:numel(out_cell)
    fprintf(fid1,'%s\n',out_cell{row});
end
fclose(fid1);
toc
```

However this feels quite convoluted and difficult to read.

Is there a more concise, simpler way to accomplish this?

Secondly, one feature I particularly like about `writetable` is the ability to include column headers. How could I incorporate this into a solution? `writetable` itself seems to explicitly require vectors of equal length and thus padding. I'm working on OS X so using `xlswrite` is not much of a viable option.

**EDIT**:

I've reduced down the necessary code by making use of tables and `writetable`:

```
con = [{A} {B} {C}];
lens = cellfun('length',con);
max_length = max(lens);
con_reg = cell(max_length,numel(lens));
con_reg(:) = {''};
con_reg(bsxfun(@le,[1:max_length]',lens)) = cellstr(num2str(vertcat(con{:})));
T = cell2table(con_reg);
ext = '.txt';
filename = strcat((genotype{1}),'-',num2str(threshold),'bpThresh',ext);
writetable(T,filename{1},'Delimiter','\t');
```

Interested if there are any more improvements that can be made.

Comment: what about save as *.csv using "csvwrite"? (http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html)

Comment: Can `csvwrite` write multiple matrices? It appears to only be able to write a single, combined matrix.

Comment: `csvwrite` works only with one matrix but there are other ways to create csv files. Check my answer below. (Ps: I can't mention your name in the comment don't know why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your code little bit to write as csv:

```
con = [{A} {B} {C}];
lens = cellfun('length',con);
max_length = max(lens);
con_reg = cell(max_length,numel(lens));
con_reg(:) = {''};
con_reg(bsxfun(@le,[1:max_length]',lens)) = cellstr(num2str(vertcat(con{:})));
% insert commas between the columns instead
wspace = repmat(',',max_length,1);
out_str = [];
for iter = 1:numel(con)
    out_str = [out_str char(con_reg(:,iter)) char(wspace)];
end
out_cell = cellstr(out_str);
% extension will be csv
ext = '.csv';

filename = strcat((genotype{1}),'-',num2str(threshold),'bpThresh',ext);

fid1 = fopen(filename,'wt');

for row = 1:numel(out_cell)
    fprintf(fid1,'%s\n',out_cell{row});
end
fclose(fid1);
```